# Do we have Akka/Scala equivalents for the OTP behaviors?

Tags: scala, erlang, akka, erlang-otp

I'm currently estimating a new project which is related to message routing and logging. I found OTP's abstractions like [event](http://www.erlang.org/documentation/doc-4.8.2/doc/design_principles/events.html#5) and [server](http://www.erlang.org/documentation/doc-4.8.2/doc/design_principles/gen_server.html#4) pretty useful for it. But due to non-technical reasons this project probably will be implemented on JVM, so I've looked at [Akka](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.2/). And haven't found anything similar.

There is 2 reasons why I want to find something similar to generic behaviors in Akka:

1. I'm not an expert in building distributed systems and like to have kind of best practices embedded into my tools.
2. All Akka's stuff like [remote references and registries](http://vasilrem.com/blog/software-development/even-simpler-scalability-with-akka-through-registryactor/) seems a bit complicated for a simple "pass from one point to another" app. It would be great if I will be able to address components of my system by simple name right "out of the box".

Am I missing something or in Akka it is a common practice to implement this kind of functionality by yourself?

Comment: If my question is just plain stupid - don't shy to point it out. It would be extremely useful.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Are you just looking for a decent messaging framework like RabbitMQ, HornetQ, ZeroMQ Kafka and the like? Need something more like Zookeeper?  Or do you need a high powered distributed computation system like Hadoop, Storm, or Hazelcast?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for this: http://akka.io/docs/akka-modules/1.3-RC2/modules/camel.html

Comment: Not exactly. It looks like a communication layer, which of cause importand. But i'm currently looking for the solutions of the problems: (a) structure my application well, even in context of several intensively communicating nodes and (b) build-in implementations of common patterns, like publish-subscribe. And doing both of these in the most standard and explored way.